# To know whether media player or FM radio is playing in android

Tags: android, media-player

I am creating an application in android in which I need to know whether the media player or FM radio is playing song. I am not able to find out whether media player or FM radio is active for the particular time. 

 
This is the first step, after finding out current running application, I need to find which media player or FM radio is running if there are multiple media players and fm radio applications. Waiting for the reply.

Thanks, 
Salil

Answer (score 0):

There is no FM radio in Android, let alone the Android SDK. With respect to "media players", there is no requirement that such apps somehow advertise themselves to you as being "media players".

Comment: Hi CommonsWare,
I have FM radio on my mobile HTC One V. 
I have seen some apps doing what I want to do.
I want to develop an application which on user interaction will play/pause the current song or play the next song or play previous song, whatever may be the current music player that is running the song.

Comment: @Salilgodbole: "I have FM radio on my mobile HTC One V" -- that was put there by HTC. There is no FM radio in Android, let alone the Android SDK. "I have seen some apps doing what I want to do" -- name any. "whatever may be the current music player that is running the song" -- this is not possible. If I write a music player, you cannot force me to do anything.